# Can't convert hprof dump

Tags: android, memory-leaks, memory-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I try convert dump from Android Device Monitor to Eclipse Memory Analyzer format. I use next command

```
hprof-conv dump.hprof converted-dump.hprof
```

and i get error

```
hprof-conv: command not found
```

I do this in a `/platform-tools` folder.
When I run the same command on another computer everything works fine.What is problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to run a binary from the current directory you need to prepend `./` to the name of the binary or use the full qualified path to the binary. E.g. if you are in `platform-tools` you can run

```
./hprof-conv /path/to/dump.hprof /path/to/converted-dump.hprof
```

if you are in the directory where `dump.hprof` is stored you need

```
/path/to/platform-tools/hprof-conv  dump.hprof converted-dump.hprof
```

or you could add `tools` and `platform-tool`s to `$PATH`. To do so, edit `.bashrc`. E.g.

```
vim .bashrc
export PATH=${PATH}:~/path/to/sdk/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/path/to/sdk/platform-tools
```

save it, and the run `source /etc/profile`, and you should be able to run every binary in `tools` and `platform-tools` without the path or the ./